# Need to find hitchhiking websites/apps

Tags: iphone

I would like to fnd some hitchhiking websites or iPhone apps where I can find somebody who is driving and I can go with him the same day before making reservations too far in advance. Is there some website that can do that for Europe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two apps which do this
http://www.carticipate.com/

And http://www.avego.com/

Both have apps location aware and are for ride sharing or hitchhiking.